# AzureCosmos DB - Implementing a query with .Contains() functionality over an array of search terms

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm querying the Azure Cosmos DB and need to apply a filter based on an array of Search terms.
Something like below:

```
 searchTerms = searchTerms.Where(s => s != null).Select(f => f.ToLower()).ToArray();
 query = query.Where(uci => searchTerms.Any(f => uci.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(f))
         || searchTerms.Any(f => uci.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(f))
         || searchTerms.Any(f => uci.User.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(f)));
```

However the query fails with an error "Input is not of type IDocumentQuery"
So, "Any" is not supported by Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.

The alternative was to use the sql query instead of using linq. SQL has 2 options "Array_contains" or "Contains" but that doesn't work because

1. Array_contains does a "=" check on the array elements rather than substring check 
   eg. SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS(["apples", "strawberries", "bananas"], "apples") AS b1
2. Contains works on a single string 
   eg. SELECT CONTAINS("abc", "ab") AS c1

[cosmos array_contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains)

[This link](https://dev.to/petereysermans/things-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-got-started-with-cosmosdb-4o05) speaks about the "like" keyword, however that also works on a single string.

The closest solution that I could come up with is below

```
searchTerms = searchTerms.Where(s => s != null).Select(f => f.ToLower()).ToArray();
foreach (string term in searchTerms) {
      query = query.Where(uci => uci.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(term)
      || uci.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(term)
      || uci.User.Company.Name.ToLower().Contains(term));
   }
```

This will add a "where" clause for each search term which is more of a hack than a solution.
Has anyone run across such situation? Any optimal suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post a sample document so that we can understand your scenario better?